# Add right padding to UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

My UITextField contains a detail disclosure button which I have used for promoting for picker view. in iOS7 the text is getting overlapped with the button. I want to add right padding to field so that the ellipsis or the text do not overlap with the button.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll get more helpful answers if you include more information in your question. In this case, please add the source code, and a screenshot of what you're getting now and how you'd like it to be different. I realize that you can't include a screenshot directly into your question until you earn more reputation, but a link to the image will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UITextField and override `textRectForBounds:` to give a rect that is narrower (and thus, padded from the right), like this:

```
- (CGRect) textRectForBounds: (CGRect) bounds {
    CGRect r = [super textRectForBounds: bounds];
    r.size.width -= 50; // or some number to be determined by experimentation
    return r;
}
```

Comment: You could have found out about this by reading the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextField/textRectForBounds: